# Java display elements within a single JTable Cell

Tags: java, xml, jtable, nodes

I am trying to make my own XML Editor and I am using a JTable to display the XML nodes. However, I have the following XML:

```
<Department id="A">
<DeptCode>Example1</DeptCode>
<DeptName>Example2</DeptName>
<li>List1</li>
<li>List2</li>
<li>List3</li>
<li>List4</li>
<li>List5</li>
<li>-Point</li>
</Department>
<Department id="B">
<DeptCode>Example1</DeptCode>
<DeptName>Example2</DeptName>
<li>List1</li>
<li>List2</li>
<li>List3</li>
<li>List4</li>
</Department>
```

...and so forth.

How would i go about displaying the "li" elements for each Department on a different row (in JTable) within a single cell? Hope the makes sense!

The closest i could get is this:

```
NodeList getElementTagName_LI = doc.getElementsByTagName("li");
            NodeList getElementTagName_dept = doc.getElementsByTagName("Department");
            //GET DEPARTMENTS
            for (int a = 0; a < getElementTagName_dept.getLength(); a++) {
                org.w3c.dom.Node allElements_dept = getElementTagName_dept.item(a);

                if (allElements_dept.getNodeType() == org.w3c.dom.Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    org.w3c.dom.Element eElement = (org.w3c.dom.Element) allElements_dept;
                    departmentID = eElement.getAttribute("id").toString();
                    deptCode = eElement.getElementsByTagName("DeptCode").item(0).getTextContent().toString();
                    deptName = eElement.getElementsByTagName("DeptName").item(0).getTextContent().toString();
     //Get Each XML List Element
                        li = eElement.getElementsByTagName("li").item(0).getTextContent().toString();
                        li1 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("li").item(1).getTextContent().toString();
                        li2 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("li").item(2).getTextContent().toString();
                        li3 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("li").item(3).getTextContent().toString();
                        li4 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("li").item(4).getTextContent().toString();

                }
                //Insert the XML Node Values within the JTable.
                dept_TableModel.insertRow(0, new Object[]{departmentID});
                dept_TableModel.setValueAt(deptCode, 0, 1);
                dept_TableModel.setValueAt(deptName, 0, 2);
                dept_TableModel.setValueAt(li+li1+li2+li3+li4, 0, 3);
            }
```

It kind of works;only if there is the same amount of list elements within the XML document for each department. But i need to make it so that it can have as many list elements as needed.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated, I have looked everywhere on google and have come up with the code for this. I tried multiple array lists but just cant get it to order correctly within the JTable.

Many thanks!
Alpaxj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably do something like this:

```
 String listLi = "";

 for(int i = 0; i < eElement.getElementsByTagName("li").getLength(); i++)
    listLi +=  eElement.getElementsByTagName("li").item(i).getTextContent().toString();
```

and then

```
 dept_TableModel.setValueAt(listLi, 0, 3);
```

Hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much for your support! Your Code worked perfectly. I just needed to clear the List after the value was set in the table using listli = "". I replaced the Li,li1,li2,li3... etc code  with yours and replaced the depttablemodel(li,li1,li2..) statement with yours and added the listLi="" and worked. It added each value into the next row which was what I wanted. Thanks again!